# Is Greg the only in-world character who notices the game mechanics?

Tags: epic-npc-man

*[Epic NPC Man](https://vldl.fandom.com/wiki/Epic_NPC_Man_List_Of_Episodes)* is a web series by Viva La Dirt League set in an online RPG, making fun of the various tropes associated with the plot and mechanics of said games. One of the running jokes is [Greg the Garlic Farmer](https://vldl.fandom.com/wiki/Greg_The_Garlic_Farmer) noticing the bizarre behavior of players (such as [Crafting](https://youtu.be/RgxKIu05dKE), or [Players being AFK](https://youtu.be/g6Fgxe2M4C0)), although it generally seems he's unable to actually act outside of the game parameters (In [Assassin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WBhb_bHgiKc), he's aware that a player is stealthing and killing NPCs, but all he can do is repeat the stock phrases even as he watches the player crouch-sneak towards him, dagger in hand).

Is Greg unique in being able to realize the unreality of his world?

Comment: Bodger the Blacksmith seems moderately self-aware; https://vldl.fandom.com/wiki/Blacksmith / https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=16&v=BnqXMJ9fEzY&feature=emb_logo

Comment: Bodger *"Ah've got quests noo"* https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=67&v=3gu0g-6TG-c&feature=emb_logo

Comment: In retrospect, [Self Aware](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zGtFrnBTsmI) has a more explicit case of self-awareness, played for laughs, and a failed attempt at inducing self-awareness in [Wood Cutter](https://youtu.be/dQ65MK5ZnHQ).

Comment: And [Mugger Scan](https://youtu.be/_mHmpvAd0gs) has the muggers notice the quest marker and fake one.

Comment: Baradun is 'killing noobs' and makes reference to how they 'just respawn'; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b0CJNpqeq8g&feature=emb_title

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bodger has a good level of self-awareness, Particularly when it comes to in-game mechanics, as can be seen in *ENG: Quest* where he explains that the Adventurer can't get his XP and complete the quest unless he sells him the Chest of Formerly Lost Souls.

And *ENG: Size Matters* where he tells Greg that he has quests of his own, now.

As mentioned in comments, *ENG: Selfaware* had gravediggers Nut and Grimble discussing the limited nature of their existence.